# Casting float to varchar looses precision

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT CAST('8.202343' AS FLOAT), CAST(CAST('8.202343' AS FLOAT(53)) AS VARCHAR)
```

produces:

| 8.202343 | 8.20234 |
| --- | --- |

but I would expect:

| 8.202343 | 8.202343 |
| --- | --- |

What is causing this issue and can SQL server be configured (ie. /wo changing the query) to prevent such loose FLOAT to VARCHAR conversion?

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ed89b9fa9be5826953f5df5dff4154a

Answer (score 1):

as per micrsoft doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#float-and-real-styles

```
SELECT CAST('8.202343' as FLOAT), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST('8.202343' as FLOAT),1)
```

As alternative you could do this:

```
select CAST(PARSENAME(8.202343,2) as VARCHAR(20))+'.'+CAST(PARSENAME(8.202343,1) as varchar(20))
```

Comment: I cannot change the query. Is it possible to change the default conversion style or override the conversion function somehow?

Comment: you should do it in your application or adapt the query as above